# OpenSCAD Troubleshooting Method : How (strategies or tools) can I find and plug a “leak” in a 3D model or in an included STL file?

Tags: debugging, openscad

I receive occasional “ERROR: The given mesh is not closed! Unable to convert to CGAL_Nef_Polyhedron.” messages from openSCAD. I have a hard time finding the origin of the problem but I suspect it might come from STL files I included in my model⁽¹⁾.

So, outside the recommended best practice in the code writing, to avoid shared surfaces, what are the strategies or tools I can use to find WHERE those leaks are (and how can I “plug” them) ?

(1) I made those STL file myself with openSCAD, from other STL files I transformed with tinkercad, and the making included taking a cut to extract writings (both sides : writing + negative of the writing), combine them with cones (minkowski), etc. - and my code itself is quite complex. So there are many possible sources for this problem and I'm looking for ways to isolate them.

Edit : Someone on a group suggested the Meshlab software to analyse the STL files.

Answer (score 0):

> Someone on a group suggested the Meshlab software to analyse the STL files.

Meshlab seems to be a good idea to me. If you go in the 'filters' menu, there is a 'Cleaning an repairing' section where you could find your solution.

Comment: I have tried to use it, but it didn't help me much, to find the source of the problem and correct it (at the source)

Comment: Then I think the easiest way is to do everything within openscad and without stl exports and imports. From what you wrote about your thinkercad process, I think this is possible.

Comment: I have indeed, noticed that there are problems with exporting and re-importings things from openscad. but in this case, Do not have this option since I'm using markings from outside.